# pwSafe on the Mac now giving error when trying to use iCloud based safe (version 4.8)

Tags: macos, icloud

Since version 4.8 of pwSafe was updated on the 8th (Mac OSx El Capitan), whenever I try to use one of my existing safes stored in iCloud, I get the following error:

```
The document "(null)" could not be opened.
```

I can easily open any of the safes stored in iCloud on my iPhone or Windows (yes, completely different apps/OS's, but mentioned as its obviously not the safes themselves).

So far I've tried uninstalling (both with and without app cleaner's assistance) and reinstalling, but with no success.

Anybody else had this problem and know of a solution, other than to wait for App77 to update their application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else was wondering - it ended up being that I had the safe in question open in a different user session, which created a lock on the safe file causing the weird error message in the user session I was currently in.

A safe can only be opened in one user session by the looks of it. Problem as such solved.